# Changing Telerik RadGrid PageSize based on other RadGrid PageSize

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I got a two RadGrid controls in my page RadGrid1 and RadGrid2 , When I change page size of any one of them I want the other one changed automatically with the same page size , I tried this :

```
protected void RadGrid1_PageSizeChanged(object sender, GridPageSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid2.PageSize = e.NewPageSize;
}

protected void RadGrid2_PageSizeChanged(object sender, GridPageSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid1.PageSize = e.NewPageSize;
}
```

but this causes a stackoverflow exception because each event called the other.

Answer (score 2):

Please try with below code snippet.

**.aspx**

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound"
    OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" 
     PageSize="2" AllowPaging="true" onpagesizechanged="RadGrid1_PageSizeChanged">
    <MasterTableView Name="Parent" DataKeyNames="ID" EditMode="PopUp">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" UniqueName="ID" HeaderText="ID">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" UniqueName="Name" HeaderText="Name">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
            </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>

<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid2_NeedDataSource"  onpagesizechanged="RadGrid2_PageSizeChanged"
PageSize="2" AllowPaging="true">
    <MasterTableView Name="Parent" DataKeyNames="ID" EditMode="PopUp">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" UniqueName="ID" HeaderText="ID">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" UniqueName="Name" HeaderText="Name">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
 protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic data = new[] {
    new { ID = 1, Name ="Name1",path="1.jpg"},
    new { ID = 2, Name = "Name2",path="2.jpg"},
    new { ID = 3, Name = "Name3",path="3.jpg"},
     new { ID = 4, Name = "Name4",path="2.jpg"},
    new { ID = 5, Name = "Name5",path="3.jpg"}
};
    RadGrid1.DataSource = data;
}


protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.IsInEditMode && e.Item is GridEditableItem)
    {
        GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        string strID = item.GetDataKeyValue("ID").ToString();
        // Access your DataKey here
    }
}



protected void RadGrid2_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic data = new[] {
    new { ID = 1, Name ="Name1",path="1.jpg"},
    new { ID = 2, Name = "Name2",path="2.jpg"},
    new { ID = 3, Name = "Name3",path="3.jpg"},
     new { ID = 4, Name = "Name4",path="2.jpg"},
    new { ID = 5, Name = "Name5",path="3.jpg"}
};
    RadGrid2.DataSource = data;
}


protected void RadGrid1_PageSizeChanged(object sender, GridPageSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid2.PageSize = e.NewPageSize;
    RadGrid2.Rebind();
}

protected void RadGrid2_PageSizeChanged(object sender, GridPageSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid1.PageSize = e.NewPageSize;
    RadGrid1.Rebind();
}
```

Comment: this will change the page index for the other grid , what I've asked was for Page Size not the Index.

Comment: Jayesh what I want to change any grid page size and the other takes the same page size. your code will just make it from one side "if i change RadGrid1 page size , RadGrid2 will change , but if I change Grid2 page size nothing will happen !!

Comment: :) Jayesh if you reviewed what I've done , you will find it's so similar to your answer except the rebind , Jayesh try this code and tell me what you find.

Comment: after changing the page size we must have to rebind the grid. (means we must have to assign datasource to grid). If we change the Size in RadGrid1 then it will automatically rebind / assign datasource using needdatasource event and for RadGrid2 we must have to handle this thing manually.

Please check below link for this http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-commands-that-invoke-rebind-implicitly.html